# Unnecessary Abuse in Notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working on the following problem and finding the abuse of notation particularly irritating:

> Let $G$ be an (additive) abelian group with subgroups $H$ and $K$. Show that $G \simeq H \oplus K$ if and only if there are homomorphisms $\pi_1 : G \to H$, $\pi_2 : G \to K$, $i_1 : H \to G$ and $i_2 : K \to G$ such that $\pi_1 i_1 = 1_H$, $\pi_2 i_2 = I_K$, $\pi_1 i_2 = 0$, and $\pi_2 i_1 = 0$, where $0$ is the map sending every element onto the zero (identity) element, and $i_1 \pi_1(x) + i_2 \pi_2(x) = x$ for every $x \in G$.

Clearly we are suppose to interpret $\pi_k$ as projections from direct products to factors, and $i_k$ as embeddings of groups into direct products of groups. But the author not only wants to say $G$ is isomorphic to $H \oplus K$ but *just is* $H \oplus K$; but at the same time $G$ isn't the direct product. This is typical of Hungerford and is really the only thing that irritates me about his book. How can we rewrite the problem without the unnecessary abuse in notation? The part giving me most trouble is "$i_1 \pi_1(x) + i_2 \pi_2(x) = x$ for every $x \in G$"

Comment: I am not sure what abuse you are seeing. The fact that he uses $\pi$ and $i$ for the functions? Change those to other letters (and make sure those other letters aren't also traditionally used for specific things... good luck with that!)

Comment: @mathguy I take no issue with using $\pi$ and $i$. What I take issue with is the fact that, e.g., $\pi_1$ is really a map from $H \oplus K$ to $H$; but the author wants to abuse notation and treat it as a map from $G$ to $H$.

Comment: No, $\pi_1$ really is a map from $G$ to $H$. You say "Clearly we are supposed to interpret $\pi_k$ as...". Yes or no, depending on what you mean by "interpret". _Thinking_ of the $\pi_k$ that way may be a good idea for the sake of understanding what's going  on. But he _says_ $\pi_1:G\to H$, and if your "interrpret" means we're supposed to think $\pi_k$ _is_ that other thing then no, we're not supposed to interpret it that way. He means exactly what he says.

Comment: It looks like you _began_ by _assuming_ that $\pi_1$ is supposed to be the canonical projection from $H\oplus K$ to $H$. But he never said that! If you begin by assuming things he never said then of course it's going to look like the notation is screwed up. He said _there exists_ $\pi_1$ with certain properties - see my answer for a $\pi_1$ that has those properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof of a stronger statement: Suppose $G,H,K$ are abelian groups. Then $G\simeq H\oplus K$ if and only if etc. Stronger because we don't assume that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$; that's actually irrelevant to the exercise as stated. Note that everywhere below I mean exactly what I say, and I prove exactly what we're asked to prove.

Suppose first that $G\simeq H\oplus K$. Let $f:G\to H\oplus K$ be an isomorphism. Define $P_1:H\oplus K\to H$ by $P_1(h,k)=h$; similarly define $P_2(h,k)=k$. Define $\pi_1:G\to H$ by $\pi_1=P_1f$. Similarly define $\pi_2=P_2f$. Define $i_1:H\to G$ by $i_1(h) = f^{-1}(h,0)$; similarly define $i_2(k)=f^{-1}(0,k)$.

Now suppose $x\in G$, and let $f(x) = (h,k)$. It follows that $\pi_1(x) =h$ and $\pi_2(x)=k$, so that $i_1\pi_1(x)+i_2\pi_2(x) = f^{-1}(h,0) + f^{-1}(0,k) = f^{-1}((h,0)+(0,k)) =  f^{-1}(h,k) = x$.

That's a proof of *exactly* what he said, or at least one direction. No abuse of notation, except for writing $f^{-1}(h,k)$ instead of $f^{-1}((h,k))$. And I left out the part about $\pi_ki_j$, which you can easily verify from the definitions. (From exactly the definitions I gave, not from some "intepretation" of them!)

Hmm. There's one part of the other direction that I don't quite see - maybe it will be clear if I write it all out. Suppose that $\pi_k$ and $i_k$ satisfy the given conditions, and define $f:G\to H\oplus K$ by $f(x)=(\pi_1(x),\pi_2(x))$. We need to show that $f$ is an isomorphism.

It's clear that $f$ is a homomorphism. And $f$ is injective: If $f(x) = (0,0)$ then $\pi_k(x)=0$, so $x=i_1\pi_1(x)+i_2\pi_2(x)=0$. I don't see how to show $f$ is surjective.

No wait. Given $h\in H$ and $k\in K$, let $x=i_1(h) + i_2(k)$. Then those conditions on $\pi_ni_m$ show that $\pi_1(x) = h$ and $\pi_2(x)=k$, so $f(x)=(h,k)$. QED.

Answer (score 3):

Not to beat a dead horse, but in fact $G$  need  *not*  be the internal direct sum of $H$ and $K$! Seems relevant to the question of whether we're "supposed to think of it as" an internal direct sum.

Note first that in my other answer I showed that a stronger result is true: Suppose $G$, $H$ and $K$ are abelian groups. Then $G\simeq H\oplus K$ if and only if there exist $\pi_k$ and $i_k$ such that etc.

Let $G=\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$. Let $H=\{(n,0)\}$ and $K=\{(0,2m)\}$. Then $G\simeq H\oplus K$, hence there exist $\pi_k$ and $i_k$ such that etc, although $G$ is certainly not the internal direct sum of $H$ and $K$.

Hence "$G$ is the internal direct sum if and only if etc" is simply false - good thing Hungerford never said that.

(Hmm, in that example it's true that $H\cap K=\{0\}$, so the internal sum $H+K$ *is* a direct sum, just not equal to $G$. Maybe more striking would be to take $H$ as above and $K=H$.)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that, $i_k\pi_k:G\longrightarrow G$ because $\pi_k$ is applied before $i_k$. It follows that $i_k\pi_k(x)\in G$ for all $x\in G$. Since $+$ is the group operation of $G$, the last statement makes perfect sense and is not notational abuse

EDIT: Seeing your last comment, it seems you misunderstand the author's intent.
They clearly want you to think of $\pi_1$ as the projection from $H\oplus K$ onto $H$, but if the map were defined on $H\oplus K$, well, what would that tell you about $G$?

Instead, the author invites you to:

$\qquad(1)$: Assuming $G\simeq H\oplus K$, find a map $\pi_1$ (and its friends) defined on $G$ that has all properties you would expect of a a projection onto $H$.

$\qquad (2)$: Assuming there is a map $\pi_1$ (and its friends) defined on $G$ that has all properties you would expect of a a projection onto $H$, show that $G\simeq H\oplus K$.

Comment: But aren't $\pi_1$ and $i_1$ really maps from $H \oplus K \to H$ and $H \to H \oplus K$, respectively?

Comment: @user193319 See the edit.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Oh...I see. So would it be better to just take the statement as saying $G = H \oplus K$, which says that every element in $G$ can be decomposed as a sum of an element in $H$ and $K$? I was thinking that $H \oplus K$ consisted of ordered pairs.

Comment: @user193319. There exist by definition maps: $i_H\colon H\to H\oplus K$ and $i_K\colon K\to H\oplus K$ and same for projections. However, maps $i_1\colon H\to G$ and $i_2\colon K\to G$ are not those maps. Rather, there exists isomorphism $f\colon G\to H\oplus K$, such that $fi_1 = i_H$ and $fi_2 = i_K$. Same for projections.

Comment: No, it's not better to take the statement as saying whatever. $H\oplus K$ _is_ a set of ordered pairs. If you "interpret" _everything_ he says to mean _exactly_ what he says all the problems you see go away. You have to do that with _all_ of it.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Okay. I am totally lost now. You seem to be contradicting Fimpellizieri, specifically his comment two up from yours, as well as Morgan Rodgers. I thought that we were dealing with something like this https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Internal_direct_product which is not defined in terms of ordered pairs. I thought that $H \oplus K$ was analogous to the direct sum for vector spaces, which, again, does not involve ordered pairs.

Comment: I think we've have established that Hungerford isn't abusing notation (although I am still very perplexed), but surely this fellow is abusing notation (see page 82): http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/mashker/files/2010/02/sol-manual-hungeford.pdf by blatantly writing $g = (h,k)$...right?

Comment: I didn't want to point out I was contradicting anyone, but I suppose I am. All the comments about how you should think of whatever this way seem wrong - if you think of everything as meaning exactly what it says it all works. (You need to "interpret" things _if_ you want to read this as a statement about internal direct products. As I show in my answer, the fact that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ really has nothing to do with it.)

Comment: Not only are we not dealing with internal direct products, the statement is _false_ for the internal direct product! See my second answer.

Comment: @MorganRodgers There's no abuse of notation in saying $G=H\oplus K$ as internal direct sum. But the stated result is _false_ with the internal direct sum - the conditions on $\pi_k$ and $i_k$ do not imply that $G=H\oplus K$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers In fact come to think of it the conditions on $\pi_k$ and $i_k$ do not even imply that $H\cap K=\{0\}$, so the internall direct sum need not even exist, equal to $G$ or not.

Comment: @user193319 David's example (see his community wiki answer) is a good one -- so yes, it's best to stick to ordered pairs. I've deleted my previous comment which was simply wrong in this regard; the direct sum $H\oplus K$ need not equal $G$ (even when it's internal, although it need not be), but they will be isomorphic nonetheless.