# Question about the solution to the exercise: prove that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ contains elements of every possible finite order

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

For the solution to the following question:

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}
$ contains elements of every possible finite order.

Proof:  For any positive integer $n$ consider the element $\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Then $n(\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb{Z})=1+n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.  Now, let $k$ be the order of $\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\frac{k}{n}\in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $n\mid k$. Thus $n$ is the order of $\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$.

I am confused about: "let $k$ can be the order of $\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $\frac{k}{n}\in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $n\mid k$. Thus $n$ is the order of $\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb{Z}$."

I thought if I have say $n=5$, then $\frac{1}{5}+\mathbb{Z}$ would have order $5$. If I translate the portions in quotes using numerical examples, say with $k=75$ and $n=5$, we have "let $75$ be the order of $\frac{1}{5}+\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\frac{75}{5}\in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $5\mid 75$.  Thus $5$ is the order of $\frac{1}{5}+\mathbb{Z}$.".

Then $\frac{1}{5}+\mathbb{Z}$ are of both orders $5$ and $75$. Either I am missing something in the text of the solution or I am misreading something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't substitute $75$ for $k$. That is equivalent to saying "Let a false statement be true". That sentence is defining $k$ to be the the order of $\frac{1}{n} + Z$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't understand the purpose of "let $k$ can be the order of $\frac{1}{n}+Z.$  Then $\frac{k}{n}\in Z,$ so that $n|k.$".  I mean if  I have $\frac{1}{n}+Z$, the order should be $n$.  So why does it start saying suppose it has order $k$?

Comment: If the confusion is that $\frac{75}{5}\in Z$, $5|75$, and so seemingly satisfies the hypotheses for it to be the order of $\frac 1 n + Z$, part of the argument (the first part) is that $n(\frac 1 n + Z) = Z$, i.e. that the order divides 5. So the only $k$s you're allowed to consider are numbers that divide $5$.

Comment: @Robbie the way it concludes with $n|K$ give one the impression that I can consider any $k$ as long as it divides $n$.  And since the order of $\frac{1}{n}+Z$ has to add up to the idenity, the only possibility would be $n$?  Is that how I should be interpreting it?

Comment: The first part proves the order is $\le n$; the second part proves that the order is $\ge n$; the conclusion is that the order is $n$.

Comment: First part of the argument shows $k|n$. Second part shows $n|k$. Thus $n=k$.

Comment: @Joe ah okay okay.  Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: @Robbie you too, thank you for clearing it up for me.

Comment: @SethMai, $k$ is a free variable. Logically, you can make the statement "let $k$ be ***the*** [anything]"  as long as you know that [anything] exists and is unique. That's simply defining $k$ to be a name for that unique object.  "75" is already the name of a constant, so you cannot define it to also be the name of some unique object that may be different from that constant, because two different objects aren't allowed to have the same name.

Comment: @Joe when I first read it, it felt really confusing and redundant.  I mean, the standard proof i have seen and from computational examples is that the order of $\frac{1}{n}+Z$ is of order $n$ by adding $\frac{1}{n}+Z$ to itself $n$-times.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes when something seems very obvious, the proof can be harder to follow, because you can be taking something for granted that the proof is trying to show.

Comment: @Joe I am going through Hungerford's undergraduate abstract algebra 3rd edition text myself.  I try to do all the exercises and check with the solutions manual after.  But, Hungerford can be terse and also the solution manual is based on the first edition of the text. The chapters and exercises are all out of order by the third edition.  Also a lot of times, Hungerford doesn't explain well the direction of the proofs in the solutions.  Another thing is that, many of the questions in his undergrad text also appears in his graduate text.   There much more theory are presented for same exercises.

Comment: Well, I'm sure you'll benefit from all of that work. And it's great that you can ask questions here. This website didn't exist when I was an undergrad.

Comment: @Joe well yesterday, I ended up frustrating Arturo Magidin here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448093/prove-that-g-cong-h-times-k-if-and-only-if-there-are-homomorphisms/4448417?noredirect=1#comment9315328_4448417, I never told him what I told you just now.  I feel really bad about it.

Comment: In that post and this one, your mistakes seem to be assuming things you cannot assume. If you can take a course in logic, or self study it, that may help firm up your proofs.

Comment: @Joe in that post, the same question is asked in hungerford's grad level text, which someone asked about here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491542/unnecessary-abuse-in-notation
The issue I had is that in one of the directions from what Hungerford is asking, it just seems that if I do exactly what he asks, i will in effect shown that $x=(g,h)$ assuming that $G\cong H\times K$.  But I don't think just following  his hints and coming up with the necessary homomorphic maps would suffice.  The solutions for his undergrad text is really terse and it leave me with more questions.

Answer (score 1):

The order of $r+\Bbb Z$ in the quotient group $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $nr\in\Bbb Z$. But $r\in\Bbb Q$, and hence $r=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a\in\Bbb Z$, $b\in\Bbb Z_{>0}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Therefore, while $r$ runs in $\Bbb Q$, $n=b$ runs over the whole $\Bbb Z_{>0}$.

Comment: your solution makes so much more sense, even without any guidepost in the direction of the proof.

Comment: In particular, $\frac1n\in\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ has order $n$.